# SQL statements vs MVC data access layer in PHP

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, data-access-layer, laravel

Modern MVC frameworks have their own implementation of data access layers that do not require SQL statements to be written. In terms of performance and scalability, are there any drawbacks, for instance, when using

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
```

instead of using prepared statements in raw SQL like

```
$user = DB::connection()->pdo->prepare("SELECT * from users where `email` = ? "  ) ;
```

Since MVC frameworks like Laravel and Cakephp also allow the latter approach, I am not sure which of the two method is better in terms of performance and scalability.

Comment: Retag the question with `Laravel`. People who are familiar with it will get to see your post and you may get a quick response.

Comment: Raw queries ~ query builder >>>> active record. Raw queries and query builder are different only by fraction of a second which is negligible. But for complicated queries, active records are very slow (to be fair, complicated queries aren't main purpose of active records. Use the right tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sub>**Rant:**
> What you call *"modern MVC frameworks"* (with few exceptions) are nowhere close implementing MVC. And those *"layers that do not require SQL statements"* are actually extremely harmful in large scale projects(where MVC should be actually used).</sub>

My advice would be to avoid use of any built-in ORM or query-builder. The ORMs that so-called "mvc frameworks" are bundled with are usually implementations of [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), which has **extremely limited** use-case. Basically, AR based implementations for domain entities are pragmatic **only** if you are using just the basic CRUD operations *(no `JOIN`s or other above-beginner level sql queries)* and only simple attribute validation *(no cross-checked fields or interactions with other entities)*. Technically you *can* use active record instances in more complicated cased, but then you ill start to incur [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html).

The best option would be to separate the domain logic from storage logic and implement [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) for each of the aspect of model layer respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used data mapper / orm library before. Basically, I am looking for the right way to use my custom-made SQL statements in abstraction layers because I feel the need to code SQL queries myself especially for complex queries. Is that the right way to use ORM libraries/data mappers? Or is that an acceptable practice when using data mappers? Any recommendations?

Comment: "Data mapper" is not library. It is a design pattern. And if you need to work with complex queries, then that is the recommended approach.

Comment: I see. When you said " 'layers that do not require SQL statements' are actually extremely harmful in large scale projects(where MVC should be actually used)," are you referring to the abstraction layers of an average MVC framework as "harmful"?

Comment: @Edville , I was referring to *"implementation of data access layers that do not require SQL statements to be written"* part.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are drawbacks both in terms of performance and scalability.

All these ORMs and ARs are quite good only with basic queries.
But when it comes to some complex issues, they become either unbearable complex or merely helpless.
There is no way to inject "USE INDEX", "DELAYED" or the like performance-boosting commands in these sleek operators.

Same goes for scalability.
Every time you're going to use whatever non-standard operator, you gonna scratch your head.

There is also a portability issue.
SQL is a *lingua franca* for the web-dewelopers, everuone could read and write it. 
While proprietary ORM can put them in a fix.

Nevertheless, your second code is no less ugly and unusable.

```
$user = DB::connection()->pdo->prepare("SELECT * from users where email=?");
```

`DB::connection()->pdo->prepare()` does not return no users. It returns a statement handle which have to be used in the following several lines to get the actual user info.
Adding tons of useless code in your scripts.
And it's ordinal case with select from scalar. Try it with `INSERT` or a mere `IN()` statement and your code will be blown up to several screens high.

Why not to make it to **really** get user info?

```
$user = DB::conn()->getRow("SELECT * from users where email=?s",$email);
```

Look - you keep your SQL yet made it usable.

Answer (score 0):

of course you will always have the overhead of running through a class and assembling the query.

Yet it helps you to prevent errors. Typos like "were `id` =" cant happen(or shouldnt). Except from that those layers already do a lot of stuff for you.

Like escaping, parsing, validating etc... so take the overhead but be sure a lot of failures or security issues wont happen